# Change string to mysql compatible date

Tags: php, date

I am getting a string in this format `dd/mm/yyyy` (ex:'06/02/2019', meaning 6th FEB 2019). How can i change this to yyyy-mm-dd and save it in mysql DB using PHP. I tried the below script but the problem is its saving like '2019-06-02' meaning 2nd JUNE 2019 in MYSQL DB. Can anyone pls suggest me what i am doing wrong.

```
$startdate=$_POST["startdate"];

$timestamp = strtotime($startdate);
    if ($timestamp === FALSE) {
         $timestamp = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $startdate));
     }
         $startdate = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);

         echo $startdate;
```

Comment: Why downvoted ?

Comment: Even if you replace the /, `06-02-2019 - 6th FEB 2019` is still not a value strtotime will understand. Those are _two_ date values, not one.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am getting the value in this format 06-02-2019. I mentioned 6th FEB just to make users understand that this is the format

Comment: `$timestamp = strtotime($startdate);` parses this into a timestamp value already - it is not the one you want, but it is still not false. So your attempt at replacing anything in the original date string afterwards, doesn’t even get executed.

Comment: ok, i understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this

```
$startdate='06/02/2019 - 6th FEB 2019'; // 06/02/2019 - 6th FEB 2019
$d1 = substr($startdate,0,10);
$t = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$d1);
var_dump($t->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: In this case also i am getting an output : 2019-06-02, which is wrong. I am expecting 2019-02-06 as the output

Comment: Hey, Perfect @Venoel. Thankx a lot..:)

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using `strtotime` so no need to use `substr` You can modify your code and get you to desire output

```
$timestamp = substr($_POST["startdate"],0,10)
$timestamp = strtotime($timestamp);
$startdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo $startdate;
```

Mysql use date format ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS’, so using date function you can simply achieve your result.

Comment: Getting an error "A non well formed numeric value encountered"